# Converting 3D coordinates to 2D and back?

Tags: opengl, c++, coordinates, sfml, glut

I'm wondering if there is a simple way to convert 3D coordinates to 2D coordinates. Also, if it's possible, to convert in the reverse direction.

I'm using OpenGL(GLUT) in my C++ project.

I am also using SFML for the 2D information (sprites text etc.)

I found out that I can use [gluProject()](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/gluProject.xml), but I have no idea how to use this.

I'm asking for a simple example of using gluProject() or another example to convert 3D coordinates (such as from the player) to 2D coordinates.

If I can't get the simple process I'm confident that I can figure out the rest.

Comment: I think you are just looking for '3d object selection' in which case there is a lot of information both on this SE as well as on google (when you know what to search for :))

Comment: If that's it, look for 'picking'.

Comment: alright, ill look aroundm thanks for the suggestion, but im also wondering how to change from 3D to 2D for health bars and such.

Comment: hey i just found [this](http://www.lighthouse3d.com/opengl/picking/index.php?openglway). is this a good example?(i was skimming xD)

Comment: This isn't your inquiry here, but [you may also find it useful to see this question about translating axes between 2D and 3D](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/10995/swapping-axis-labels-between-2d-and-3d-coordinates).

Comment: for health bars (that need to be in specific 3d locations) consider billboarding a quad rather than 2d/3d conversion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert between 3D and 2D coordinates in a variety of ways, some of which have more meaning than others. For example you could just drop the Z coordinate, yielding an (x,y) pair, but that probably doesn't do what you want semantically.

But you're specifically asking how to convert between model, world or view space 3D and screen space 2D as used by your graphics API, it sounds like. This primarily involves application of the appropriate transformation matrix, as well as performing the perspective division by W and any viewport transformations that may be warranted. gluProject does exactly this operation, all you have to do is provide it with input coordinates and matrices.

gluProject assumes the input coordinates `objX`, `objY`, and `objZ` to be in model space, but they can be anywhere as long as the matrices you provide it via the `model` and `proj` parameters have associated meaningful values. The format of the `model` and `proj` matrices is an array of 16 floating point values, the same kind of data you'd get from `glGetFloatv` and such. The `view` parameter is an array of 4 integers representing the position and size of your viewport (from `glGetIntegerv` for example).

To perform the operation in reverse, you can use gluUnproject. Note that since you'll have a 2D coordinate you'll have manually specify an arbitrary depth value. The 3D → 2D conversion perforce loses data, so you must invent new data when going in the other direction.